# Problems with subcaption in frontiers documentclass

Tags: captions, subcaption

If I use the subcaption package within the frontiersSCNS documentclass, the subfigure counter seems to be not reset properly. The MWE

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\def\firstAuthorLast{Sample {et~al.}}

\begin{document} \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1} \end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large A
        \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:2a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
        \centering\large B
        \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:2b}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

produces [image]

Exchanging `frontiersSCNS` with `article` results in the expected document

[image]

Note that I do not care about the difference in layout. I just want the numbering to be 1a), 1b), 2a), 2b) and not 1a), 1b), 2c), 2d).

What is odd is that the frontiers template itself loads the `subcaption` package and thus implies that it is safe to use. The frontiers class and template can be downloaded here: http://www.frontiersin.org/design/zip/Frontiers_LaTeX_Templates.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took a short look into the class file and have found the line `\newcounter{subfigure}`. This is a bad idea since this prevents the `subcaption` package from defining this counter for itself (with different settings). One could use

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{subfigure}{figure}
\makeatother
[...]
```

as work-around, but of course it would be better if this bug would be fixed in the document class instead.

P.S.: Maybe I should detect this situation in `caption3.sty` / `\DeclareSubType` and issue a warning and try to correct this: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/65

**Addendum 2020-01-02**

I finally found some time to take a closer look at this issue and implementing my suggestion. But it does not help in this case, because:

The `frontiersSCNS` is loading the `subcaption` package before defining `figure`, and for this reason the `subcaption` package does not define `subfigure`. The `frontiersSCNS` could do this after defining `figure` with `\DeclareCaptionSubType`, but instead it defines its very own `subfigure` environment (as floating environment!) which is incompatible to the `subcaption` package.

So no, the usage of `subcaption` is not safe here, quite the opposite. It's not clear to me why the `frontiersSCNS` document class does load the `subcaption` package but does not make any use of it and defines its own stuff instead.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was rather based on @Julian Karch answer. The good news is that it works, the bad news is that you will have to set the counter several times as long as there are subfigures. The main idea is to (1) reset the figure counter and (2) reset the subfigure counter. Ugly, but this Frontiers latex class is not a good class, to say the least.

```
\setcounter{figure}{1}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
```

```latex
\begin{subfigure}
\setcounter{figure}{2}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1}
        \caption{blah-1}
        \label{fig:blah1}
    \end{minipage}  
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img2}
        \caption{blah-2}
        \label{fig:blah2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Subfigures for the broken Frontiers template.}
    \label{fig: subfigures}
\end{subfigure}
```

Comment: I'm using this, it works, but for some reason breaks the `\subref{}` command

Answer (score 0):

By accident, I found out that the relevant counter is called `subfigure`. Thus, by inserting    `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` between the two figures one obtains the desired behavior. This is of course a rather "quick and dirty" solution.

Comment: Because the solution is rather quick and dirty I am not accepting it for the moment with the hope that somebody will provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new counter and a command to use it.

```
\newcounter{subfigCounter}[figure]
\newcommand{\countSubFig}{\stepcounter{subfigCounter} (\textbf{\Alph{subfigCounter}})\xspace}
```

Then, to add the subfigures:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1}
        \text{\countSubFig Foo.}
    \end{minipage}  
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img2}
        \text{\countSubFig Bar.}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Subfigures for the broken Frontiers template.}
    \label{fig: subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

It is a bit ugly, but solves the problem even for multiple subfigures in the text. The only thing left to solve is referencing the subfigures. I have tried with `\refstepcounter` but it did not work straightforward.