# Undefined subtype 'subfigure'

Tags: templates, subcaption, overleaf, includegraphics

I am trying to enter some subfigures in my tex document as follows:

```
%%% FIGURE %%%
\begin{figure}[!hptb]
\begin{center}
%\includegraphics[width=15cm]{query.jpeg}
    \subfloat(a){\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{1.jpeg}} 
    \subfloat(b){\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{2.jpeg}} 
    \subfloat(c){\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{3.jpeg}} 
\end{center}
\caption{\small bla bla bla}
\label{fig:f_fig}
\end{figure}
```

The packages that I am using are

```
\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%For subfigures
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

I am using overleaf. The template that I am using is:
https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-frontiers-journal/myxxkvjwqhrv

The error that I am getting is: `Undefined subtype 'subfigure'`.

Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: I don't get an error message when I make your code minimally compilable (by placing it into a trunk document with suitably placed `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` directives). That said, I think you have syntactic mistakes in your code: Shouldn't you be using square brackets instead of round parentheses around `a`, `b`, and `c`?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511120/problems-with-subcaption-in-frontiers-documentclass

Comment: @P.M. I have not understood the right order in that question. Could you please mention the packages and order that are mentioned in the answer on that post? Mico, I am going to follow your advice and let you know if it fixes the issue. Thanks

Comment: @Mico, I have tried as follows: `\subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.jpeg}}`  but I am still getting the same error. I think the problem is in the use of frontiers' template. With arXiv I had no any issue with that

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Support here. On the first sight, this looks like a bug in the Frontiers template. There are other things in the template that could be called _unfortunate_, e.g. the inclusion of `\graphicspath{{g:/artwork/oup/bioinfo/}}` which doesn't make any sense. I'm really not sure how much this is useful in solving the problem.

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you so much for your comment. I have found a possible alternative to fix this issue with subfigures. I hope it can help. Thank you so much for all the comments and help you all provided

Comment: To me it seems that the frontiersSCNS document class is incompatible to the subcaption package. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511316/205700 "So no, the usage of subcaption is not safe here, quite the opposite."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good alternative to not get the errors because of the subfloat or subfigure.
It consists of using tabular. So for example:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}

%For figurers and subfigures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    %%%FIGURE%%%
    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{1.jpeg}
            \small(a)
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{2.jpeg}
            \small(b)
        \end{tabular}
      \caption
        {%
          \small bla bla bla}
          \label{fig:test}%
          
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I hope this can help other researchers who use (and struggle too) this template.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

With recent `subcaption` package (version 1.3) this work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
%For figurers and subfigures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}%{1.jpeg}}
\hfil
\subfloat[][]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}%{2.jpeg}}
    \caption{bla bla bla}
    \label{fig:test}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details of the `subfloat` macro as defined in the `subcaption` documentation, see section 7, pp 12.

**Addendum**
Proposed solution doesn't work fine with `frontiersSCNS` document class. Apparently it call and redefine many packages. Among them are `caption`, `subcaption` package. Considering this a wee bit modified above solution:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}

\begin{document}
   \begin{figure}[ht]
   \centering
   \small
\subfloat[][]{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}   \\%{1.jpeg}}
   (a)

   \medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}   \\%{2.jpeg}}
    (b)
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{fig:test}%
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

produce

[image]

What I suppose is not desired result. In compilation it complain that `subfigure` is *not defined*.

However, with only one complain gives the following solution:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\subfloat[][]{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}   \\%{1.jpeg}}
    (a)

    \medskip
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-duck}   \\%{2.jpeg}}
     (b)
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{fig:test}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not clear, if you like to have onne column document. In this case you need to insert command `\onecolumn` after `\begin{document}` and enclose image for example in `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\onecolumn
\lipsum[66]
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \small
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-duck}   \\%{1.jpeg}}
    (a)
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-duck}   \\%{2.jpeg}}
     (b)
\end{minipage}
\caption{bla bla bla}
\label{fig:test}%
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have sub-captions on the right side of image, as you get with compiling your answer, that you only need to remove `\\` after `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: This works in `article` class, not the Frontiers one in the original question!

Comment: @kensaii, you are (only) partly right. See addendum to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I can agree with this solution. It works, but also note that the last piece of code cannot compile. I have to adjust a bit, but it's not a big deal. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @kensaii, what not working? What you adjust? Can show me error(s)? I tested again and it works!