# Use subfigure environment of frontiers documentclass

Tags: subcaption

I am trying to use the `subfigure` environment of the subcaption package in a paper for frontiers.
You may find the used [template](https://www.frontiersin.org/about/author-guidelines) here.

The question of [Problems with subcaption in frontiers documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511120/problems-with-subcaption-in-frontiers-documentclass) already pointed out that the frontiers template is making things difficult...
Ultimately I want to use the `phantomsubcaption` to be able to reference subfigures in one big figure, but the compiler does not know the command.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}

\usepackage{url,hyperref,lineno,microtype,subcaption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\def\firstAuthorLast{Sample {et~al.}} %use et al only if is more than 1 author

\begin{document}

Test

\begin{figure}
     \begin{subfigure}{15cm}
         \centering
         \phantomsubcaption
         \label{fig:subtest}
         \includegraphics{logo1}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Hello}
     \label{fig:test}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```